# I received timeout when i curl to pod on worker k8s

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to curl to my pod via the service, but I received a timeout.

ex. master ip : 10.1.1.1
worker1 ip : 10.1.1.2
worker2 ip : 10.1.1.3

I successfully installed Kubernetes using Kubespray on Red Hat 9.0. However, when I created a pod and service and attempted to curl it, the operation failed on Red Hat 9.0 with a timeout. Interestingly, the same operation worked on Red Hat 8.6, even though everything was running as expected. Despite multiple attempts to reinstall, the issue persists. This is surprising as I've encountered no problems with Red Hat 9.0 in other projects.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

curl -vk http://10.1.1.1:31348/

- Trying 10.1.1.1:31348...
- connect to 10.1.1.1 port 31348 failed: Connection timed out
- Failed to connect to 10.1.1.1 port 31348: Connection timed out
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (28) Failed to connect to 10.1.1.1 port 31348: Connection timed out